# Навигация по якорным ссылкам

Tags: javascript, ссылки

Добрый день. Имеется некий код, для плавной анимации по якорным ссылкам. Но есть шапка навигации, которая находиться на других всех страницах сайта.
В моем коде ошибка, ведь значение id передается как "index.php#id", а нужно чтобы в переменную top входило значение id равное "#id"
Помогите пожалуйста убрать значение "index.php" в переменной. Без якорных ссылок с "index.php" не будут работать ссылки с других страниц. Сразу оговорюсь, использую вставку в php , поэтому такие костыли. Или же главную страницу оставить со своим header'ом, а на всех страницах создать свой код header'а))) Но думаю что поможете решить более красиво. Спасибо

```
    // плавная прокрутна до нажатого пункта меню
$("nav li").on("click",".nav_a", function (event) {
    // исключаем стандартную реакцию браузера
    event.preventDefault(); 
    // получем идентификатор блока из атрибута href
    var id  = $(this).attr('href');       
    // находим высоту, на которой расположен блок
    console.log(id);
    var top = $(id).offset().top-60;
    // анимируем переход к блоку, время: 800 мс
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 800);
});
```

Comment: `var id  = "#" + $(this).attr('href').split("#")[1];`

Comment: Спасибо большое! помогло ваше решение